# Vue.js - this.$http.get is not working

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-resource

I am developing project in laravel with Vue js.

> below is my code and when I use **this.$http.get** method of
>   Vue-resource js I am not getting anything but if I use **$.getJSON**
>   method I'm getting all the records from database

**brand.blade.php**

```
@section('content')

<div class="container">

        <brands></brands>

    </div>

    <template id="brand-template">

        <ul>

            <li v-for="brand in list.brand"> @{{ brand }}  </li>

        </ul>

    </template>

@endsection

@push('scripts')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src = "public/js/brand.js"></script>
@endpush
```

**brand.js**

```
Vue.component('brands',{

template: '#brand-template',

data: function(){

    return{

        list: []
    }

},

created: function(){

    this.$http.get('api/brands', function(brand){
    // if I use $.getJSON then it'e working perfect and I'm getting all the records
      this.list = brand;

    }.bind(this));

}

});

new Vue({

el: '.container'


})
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on I can't figure out.

Comment: Can you show us how you setup vue? Did you actually add the vue-resource? Is this.$http undefined or the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VueResource returns a [response](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md#response) object.  Try using `.body`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    posts: []
  },
  mounted: function() {
    var vm = this
   this.$http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(function(response) {
     vm.posts = response.body
    })
  }
})
```

```css
[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.8/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue.resource/1.0.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="post in posts">
      {{ post.title }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean like this  : 
this.$http.get('api/brands', function(brand){

          this.list = brand.body;

        }.bind(this));

Comment: can you post code for this issue here so I can understand better way and in future other developer also can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I'm getting error in this line .then(response =>//(here getting error) this.list = response.body)

Comment: @djones thanks it's working. I have also test with mzabriskie/axios package. and I thing I suit axios more. thanks by the way.